# sum of fields in condition of another filed duplicate ?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a simple table with 2 columns

```
item | num
foo | 32
foo | 22
bar | 12
baz | 3
baz | 2
bar | 25
```

i need to get sum of num in case of items have the same value
so the result like

```
item | num
foo | 54
bar | 37
baz | 5
```

i can do this by PHP but i have no clue if it can be done by a direct query
i made a small research and i found that i can do the sum with a condition but it returns a single result

```
   item | num
    foo | 54
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select item,sum(num) as num from yourTable group by item
```